# Can't use JFoenix on JavaFX maven using Apache NetBeans

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I install the dependency, I build it, clean build it and build with dependencies yet I got this error, and I don't know what cause the error. I am new to javaFX maven and I want to expand my knowledge in it.

Version of jfeonix: 9.0.10

Error:

```
 BUILD FAILURE
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Total time:  2.940 s
    Finished at: 2020-12-28T13:21:15-08:00
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Failed to execute goal org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.4:run (default-cli) on project OnCo: Error: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
    To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace of the error. I see the `run` goal is what failed, which means it's possible the problem is with your code and not Maven. If you don't see a stack trace then follow the advice of the error you do see: "_To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch_". Also, please provide a [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: What JDK are you using ?

Comment: I did manage to fix it, the problem is I have JDK 8 installed on my computer and when I run netbeans the JDK 8 will be loaded by default. I uninstall JDK 8 on my computer and automatically netbeans load the JDK 11. I don't know how to set the JDK 11 by default and change JDK to 8 when I needed it.